# What is the difference between @EnableWebSocket and @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I want to enable sockets in a Spring application and in the documentation came up 2 ways of using them, plain and with STOMP enabled.

I understand that the later is backed up by a message broker but did not find any good explanation of this feature.

So, my question would be, what does Spring bring in the back scenes when `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` is used, compared to `@EnableWebSocket` ?

Comment: You already stated the differences yourself. The `@EnableWebSocket` enables plain websockets, if you want to use stomp you need a broker and need to the `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` to indicate this.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for the quick comment. I was wondering if there is any documentation that describes this better. Would an application work as-is if the EnableWebSocket is switched to EnableWebSocketMessageBroker ? Put it other way, I wanted to read about this in more depth and did not find articles other than tutorials.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I have read so far, the difference consists in the fact that the later (`@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`) offers a better handling for the exchanged messages. In order to keep them somehow in controll, a very good approach is to use a message broker:

- easy to broadcast to intersted parts. Otherwise you have to keep trace of session and to iterate through them in order to send a message to each client who is interested
- assuring the message got to the client. Out of the box, a message broker offers acknowledgement flags that will be interchanged between client and server in order to assure the message transmission and interception

**Note**: the annotation `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` does not by default add an underlying full-featured Broker, but a "Simple one". 
The simple version:

- supports subset of STOMP: SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE, MESSAGE
- no acks, receipts, transactions
- simple message sending loop
- not suitable for clustering

A full-featured one will add more functionalities, that can be found on its presentation documentation.
(read more in http://rstoyanchev.github.io/s2gx2013-websocket-browser-apps-with-spring)

Other nice to read reference: [Message queues vs sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668028/message-queues-vs-sockets), [The MessageBroker WebSocket Subprotocol](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hapner-hybi-messagebroker-subprotocol-00.html)